# How can we find an object in empty space without a reference point?

Tags: reference-frames, observers

I've heard that to locate an object in space, we use a reference point. So, how can we find an object in empty space without a reference point?

Comment: Please reconsider and rephrase your question.  It's not clear what your premise is or what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what this has to do with expanding space, but let me give you the basic methodology.

First, locating an object is fairly simple. You see something, there it is (plus or minus a bit depending on lensing effects and whether or not you want to know where it is in the present). That was easy.

Second, no matter how empty the rest of space is, I can guarantee you there will be at least two objects; what you just observed and yourself. If nothing else, you can always choose yourself to be a reference point (might I also say what a reasonable and practical reference point you make). In general, you choose whatever point of reference you want to suit your needs. So long as you can reasonably maintain knowledge of the reference point, you can locate everything in relation to it.

Let me rephrase, as an entity existing in the universe, you cannot be in a situation where there is absolutely nothing to use as a reference point; using yourself as a reference will always be a valid and useful option.